# if condition on numpy array to check if it's equal to a value

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 1D array that increases according to the number of rounds, first starts by

```
a = np.array([5])  # round 1 
a = np.array([5, 5]) # round 2 
a = np.array([5, 5, 5]) # round 3
...
```

how to check for an arbitrary number of rounds so that everytime I run it, it will check

```
if a == 5:       # pseudo if a = np.array([5, 5]) == 5
   # do something
```

is there a way to do it?

Comment: What's supposed to happen with `a` is `np.array([5,3,4,5]`?

Comment: it's supposed to be np.array([5]) but whenever I change the number of batches it's adding up so I don't know if it's normal or not

Comment: For lists `[5,5]+[5]` produces `[5,5,5]`.

Answer (score 1):

The Python `all` operator handles this.

```
if all(a == 5):
```